# Bundling a remote React project with Rollup & babel

Tags: javascript, typescript, babeljs, bundler, rollupjs

I'm trying to fetch a remote React project (that uses typescript) and bundle it with Rollup. This is my setup so far:

1. Fetch the remote React project and store it in a temporary folder
2. Using Rollup's Javascript API, bundle the project with these input/output options:

```js
const inputOptions: RollupOptions = {
  input: "FOLDER_PATH/App.tsx",
  output: {
    file: "bundle.jsx",
  },
  external: ["react", "react-dom"],
  plugins: [
    typescript({ tsconfig: "../tsconfig.json" }),
    commonjs(),
    resolve(),
    babel({ presets: ["@babel/preset-react"] }),
  ],
};

const outputOptionsList: OutputOptions[] = [
  {
    file: "./dist/bundle.jsx",
    format: "cjs",
  },
];
```

This bundling process currently fails with this error: `Error [RollupError]: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)`

The React app I'm testing is a very simple one, with one component that looks like this:

```
import React from "react";

const App = ({ name }: { name: string }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Hello {name}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the file where you do ReactDom.render... your App component
as input to roll-up.
And you bundle will always be a js file.

```
input: "FOLDER_PATH/main.ts",
  output: {
    file: "bundle.js",
  },
```